# how to read CSV file in Map/Reduce?

Tags: csv, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a large CSV file that is in the size of 6GB, comma-delimited. Below is the mapper function

```
@Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] tokens = value.toString().split(",");

        String crimeType = tokens[5].trim();      // column #5 is the crime type in the CSV file, serving key
//      int year = Integer.parseInt(tokens[17].trim()); // the year when the crime happened

        int year = 2010;

        CrimeTypeKey crimeTypeYearKey = new CrimeTypeKey(crimeType, year);

        context.write(crimeTypeYearKey, ONE);
}
```

As you can see, I use ".split" to break down each row (or column?). I am wondering how you can use OpenCSV in this case? please give me an example, thanks a lot

Comment: In a effective way probably not. Is there any particular reason why you want to use OpenCSV?